# Handling user notifications on iOS 10

Tags: push-notification, push, ios10

I have troubles determining when the user taps on a user push notification on iOS 10.

So far, I have been using the `-[UIApplicationDelegate application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:]` which is called when

- `Case 1`: the application is active and the push is received
- `Case 2`: when the user launched the app after taping a received notification

This method comments explicitly say

> Note that this behavior is in contrast to application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:, which is not called in those cases, and which will not be invoked if this method is implemented.

All this work as expected.

Now iOS 10 deprecated this delegate method and introduced the `UserNotification` framework which I cannot use because I'm still targeting iOS 8 and 9.

When my app is running on iOS 10 and a push is received while the app is active (`Case 1`), the `-[AppDelegate application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:]` is called correctly.

Again on iOS 10, when the user starts the app by tapping a notification (`Case 2`) this method  **is not called**.

I realise that when I implement the older `-[UIApplicationDelegate application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:]` it is the one that gets called in the  `Case 2`

On iOS 8 and 9, in the `Case 2` it is the `-[AppDelegate application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:]` method is called.

Does it mean that I have to update my application and implement the older delegate just for iOS 10?

So the question is, what is the proper implementation of handling the user interaction of a received push on iOS 10 without using the `UserNotification` framework.

cheers,
Jan

Comment: If you compiled the app for iOS 9 it should be backwards compatible and therefore you could, in theory, disregard the deprecation notice because you would not be targeting iOS 10, but iOS 9 where this methods should work. I am facing the same problem now and there is already an openradar for that, I suggest you keep an eye on it as it seems that this behavior is a bug on iOS 10 beta releases. http://www.openradar.me/27822963

Comment: Exactly. Thanks for the openradar link, I'll follow it

Comment: Still not fixed in iOS 10 beta 7

Comment: Same fir iOS 10 beta 8 :/

Comment: Same for iOS 10 GM :/ Does it mean that on iOS 10 we have to use a callback that is deprecated on iOS 10 

Comment: Need to use UseNotification framework. I have implemented code for iOS 10 : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39490605/push-notification-issue-with-ios-10?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: Has apple answered to the radar yet? They really should release an iOS bugfix version for that.

Comment: Apple closed it as duplicat and said that it is under investigation

Comment: Has someone opened a Technical Support Incident about this with apple? https://developer.apple.com/support/technical/

Comment: For us it is happening with the official iOS 10.0.1 release. Unfortunately we did not come across this earlier. I opened a Technical Support Incident, hopefully Apple answer soon.

Comment: didReceiveRemoteNotification is never getting called in case 2 regardless iOS cersion.  Instead: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1657534-launch_options_keys

Comment: i am still facing the same issue in iOS 10.1.1, does apple fixed this issue?

Comment: Has anyone seen this issue since iOS 10.2.1 release? Seems to be fixed.

Comment: What's wrong with Adam's answer? Or why isn't his answer considered better? Can you please explain?

Comment: In my initial question, I was not mentioning nor using UNNotifications framework at all. It simply appeared to be a iOS 10 bug

Comment: @AshishShah Could you please tell me which method gets executed when the app is in background and receives user notification?

Comment: @Jan Could you please tell me which method gets executed when the app is in background and receives user notification?

Comment: @ArgaPK without using the `UNNotifications`, no method is called unless the user taps on the notification. If you want to monitor when the notification is received when the app is in the background, have a look at `UNNotifications`. This is out of scope of my original question though

Comment: @Jan Thank you, I will see it , but i was looking for the solution in User Notification framework.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This has been fixed in iOS 10.1 Beta 1 !!

The `-[UIApplicationDelegate application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:]` is correctly called when the user taps on a notification.

Comment: it seam to be corrected already in iOS 10.0.2. If anyone got some official information about it, I'll be late to see it !

Comment: When was the 10.0.2 released?

Comment: iOS 10.0.2 had been release around October 14, 2016

Comment: I'm using iOS 10.0.2 and the issue is still happening. :(

Comment: i am getting the same issue 10.1.1

Comment: Is it possible that the app must be running on 10.1 AND the app must have been built for iOS 10 with Xcode 8, in order for the bad behavior to be absolved?

Comment: Has anyone seen this issue since iOS 10.2.1 release?

Comment: @grane2212 i am experiencing the issue today.

Comment: @dirtydanee I think this still might be an issue. I haven't tried reproducing this issue recently. Will need to report this to apple.

Comment: Which method gets executed when the app is in background and receives notification? (User Notification Framework)

Answer (score 24):

Swift code for iOS 10:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.currentNotificationCenter()
        center.delegate = self
    }

    // ...

    return true
}

@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceiveNotificationResponse response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: () -> Void) {

    print(response.notification.request.content.userInfo)        
}

@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresentNotification notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

    print(notification.request.content.userInfo)
}
```

Comment: If I understand this all correctly. For iOS 10: the 2 delegate methods don't have a callback for when the user recieves a notification( doesn't tap) and still you must use the non-deprrcated: `-[AppDelegate application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:]`. Is that correct?

Comment: You can get it in `willPresentNotification` function @Honey

Comment: @DungTran that is correct. I asked this question a while ago. You would get 2 callbacks upon receiving  if app is in foreground. I just think the call acks are semantically different. `didReceiveRemoteNotitication` is just purely for receiving...its more for the purpose of **updating** your app. `willPresent` is more for **notifying**

Comment: Yes, I tested it. The func `didReceiveRemoteNotification` isn't called with `UserNotification` in iOS 10.

Comment: @DungTran I'm sorry I meant `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHand‌ler`. <-- This is called!

Comment: @DungTran Could you please tell me which method gets executed when the app is in background and receives user notification?

Comment: @ArgaPK _didReceiveRemoteNotification_

Comment: @AdamBardon didreceiveRemoteNotification is not executing and it is also deprecated.  i am using user notification framework

Comment: @ArgaPK oh, you're right, I'm still supporting iOS 10.3 so that's probably why it's not showing deprecated for me

Comment: @AdamBardon In User Notification , local /remote notifications handling are same, now if the app is in foreground and we receive notification than will present delegate method of user notification will execute, and if user taps on notification or action associated with that notification than did receive delegate method of user notification will execute , but i wanted to know that how to perform a task when app is in background and receives notification?

Comment: @ArgaPK as I said, _didReceiveRemoteNotification_ works for me

Comment: @AdamBardon but it is not working now, both didReceiveRemoteNotification with and without completion handler is not working? well i should also mention that i am right checking it in simulator, will it be executed on real iOS device?

Comment: @ArgaPK simulator might be the issue, as it is unable to receive push notifications, try with real device

Answer (score 15):

We were facing the same problem here and we were only able to solve this problem on iOS 10 GM release by using the code on the answer given here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/54332

```
     - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {  

           NSOperatingSystemVersion version = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] operatingSystemVersion];
           if (version.majorVersion == 10 && version.minorVersion == 0) {
              [self application: application 
   didReceiveRemoteNotification: userInfo    
         fetchCompletionHandler: ^(UIBackgroundFetchResult result) { 

            }];
       }
```

With this fix our code started working again both on iOS 9 and 10.

We also had to change the way we handle [application state behavior (UIApplicationStateActive, UIApplicationStateInactive and UIApplicationStateBackground)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationstate?language=objc) on push notifications, as it seems it also changed on iOS 10

**EDIT**:

- It seems that application state behavior is back to normal on latest iOS 10 versions.

Comment: how did the application state changed on iOS10?

Comment: We faced problems like the ones described here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/54415 but I haven't tested on GM yet, so I'm not able to confirm if this is still a problem...

Comment: @andresk Could you please tell me which method gets executed when the app is in background and receives user notification?