# Push notification not receiving in iOS 10

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, ios10

My App is in Appstore. Push notification is working fine in iOS 9, but in iOS 10 it is not working. I am not receiving any push notification for iOS 10 devices. I have checked the device token and certificate in my server. All are correct. I have also checked the notification properties in settings app. All are fine. But I didn't receive any notification. I just switch OFF and ON the notification for my app. And I opened my app to check whether device token is changing or not. It is changed and updated to my server. Then I am receiving notification properly. It is working fine now for my device.

I am worried whether this will affect for all users or only me. Anyone find the proper solution please let me know.

Thanks in advance

Comment: try this type code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39382852/didreceiveremotenotification-not-called-ios-10/39383027#39383027

Comment: I checked the previous solution. But my app don't have iOS 10 SDK. Then how it should affect for iOS 10.

Comment: you are download or upgrade your xcode 8 may be upgrade xcode.

Comment: For me older app which is already in AppStore is not working

Comment: add  new framework in xcode 8 for push notification. all push notification app on app store is not working in ios 10 that it is upgrade your application on xcode 8.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handling user notifications on iOS 10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38940193/handling-user-notifications-on-ios-10)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Push Notification is not working on iOS 10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39489182/push-notification-is-not-working-on-ios-10)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Need some changes for iOS 10  with xCode 8 GM 
You need to implement UserNotifications.framework and their delegate methods to get work of push notifications.

I have resolved my issue using new UserNotifications.framework.
Please follow this link : [Push notification issue with iOS 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39490605/push-notification-issue-with-ios-10?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: Faced same issue. So I have re-submitted my apps to Appstore with xCode 8 GM for iOS 10.

Comment: @AshishShah No need to implement `UserNotification`. It can still be done with `UIUserNotificationSettings`. You just need to enable the capabilities for Push notifications which will make a `.entitlement` file in your project.

Comment: I agree with @Ra

Answer (score 7):

"**UserNotifications**" is not mandatory in iOS10. "**UIUserNotificationSettings**" still works in iOS10.

If you have the following code , it should work in iOS10.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
```

But if you are building with **Xcode8** and above, makes sure that you have the following entry in your **entitlements**. This entry will be added automatically once you enabled "Push Notifications" in "**Capabilities**".

```
<key>aps-environment</key>
<string>development</string>
```

In release-distribution build this will be automatically changed to the 
following

```
<key>aps-environment</key>
<string>production</string>
```

Answer (score 3):

We need to change some code for iOS 10.

Appdelegate.h

```
#import <UserNotifications/UserNotifications.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate,UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate> 
@end
```

Check os version

```
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GRATERTHAN_OR_EQUALTO(v)  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)
```

Register notification

```
- (void)registerForRemoteNotifications {
    if(SYSTEM_VERSION_GRATERTHAN_OR_EQUALTO(@"10.0")){
        UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
        center.delegate = self;
        [center requestAuthorizationWithOptions:(UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge) completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error){
             if(!error){
                 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
             }
         }];  
    }
    else {
        // Code for old versions
    }
}
```

Handel delegate method

```
//foreground app.
-(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler{
    NSLog(@"User Info : %@",notification.request.content.userInfo);
    completionHandler(UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge);
}

-(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response withCompletionHandler:(void(^)())completionHandler{
    NSLog(@"User Info : %@",response.notification.request.content.userInfo);
    completionHandler();
}
```

Comment: Not necessary, we can still use the same `UIUserNotification` for iOS 10. Only difference is to add the Push Notifications entitlement in Capabilities

Answer (score 1):

On iOS 10 is necessary add the Push Notifications entitlement, so if you "Fix Issue" in Capabilities the problem will be resolved automatically.