# Push notification in NotificationCenter return nil in userinfo - Swift3

Tags: ios, push-notification, swift3

I had update then source code from Swift 2.2 to Swift 3.0 for push notification. But I can not get the userinfo. It will return nil.
Can anyone help?

Here in the app delegate to received the push notification:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {

        // Define identifier
        let notificationName = Notification.Name("PushNotificationMessageReceivedNotification")

        // Register to receive notification
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(MenuViewController.remoteNotificationReceived), name: notificationName, object: userInfo)

        // Post notification
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: notificationName, object: nil)
    }
```

In other viewController I want to received the push notification and do some action:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.delegate = self

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(MenuViewController.remoteNotificationReceived(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "PushNotificationMessageReceivedNotification"), object: nil)

    }

func remoteNotificationReceived(_ notification: Notification)
    {
        print("Notification:\(notification.userinfo)");
}
```

Comment: see this once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39382852/didreceiveremotenotification-not-called-ios-10/39383027#39383027

Comment: you are sending nil user info at NotificationCenter.default.post(name: notificationName, object: nil)

Comment: if you want to send user info Post must be like this NotificationCenter.default.post(name: notificationName, object: SOME_USER_INFO_OBJ)

Comment: See my ans. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39504334/push-notification-not-receiving-in-ios-10/39694689#39694689

Answer (score 1):

Pass UserInfo When Post Notification 
Like This :-

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {

        // Define identifier
        let notificationName = Notification.Name("PushNotificationMessageReceivedNotification")

        // Register to receive notification
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(MenuViewController.remoteNotificationReceived), name: notificationName, object: userInfo)

        // Post notification
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: notificationName, object: nil, userInfo :userInfo)
    }
```