# Push Notification isn't working on the iPhone all devices (Xcode8) version

Tags: push-notification, ios10

I've developed one application in that i've implemented push notification. I am not receiving any push notification for iOS 10 devices. I have checked the device token and certificate in my server.

This registration seems to be successful even on iOS 10 since Application `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` is then called, so I am receiving a token from APNS.

The problem is that when I send a push notification to this device, Application `didReceiveRemoteNotification` is never called.

Now, here it is said that the methods on `UIApplicationDelegate` is deprecated on iOS 10 and I should implement `userNotificationCenter(:didReceive:withCompletionHandler:)` and `userNotificationCenter(:willPresent:withCompletionHandler:)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handling user notifications on iOS 10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38940193/handling-user-notifications-on-ios-10)

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure that my didReceiveRemoteNotification function is called when I received a notification on my iPhone6iOS10, Xcode8

Please check your token, certificate, password again

Then,

1. Check your push notification in your project "Capabilities" if it's on ?
2. Check your entitlements file
3. Check "Code Signing Entitlements" in "Build Settings"