# iOS push notifications - didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler: never called in foreground

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

I have implemented remote notifications in my app, however I have problems with `didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:`.

When the phone's screen is locked, I am getting the notification. If the user swipes the notification, app comes back to foreground and `didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` is called.

But if the app is running in the foreground, `didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` is never called. What might be the reason?

I'm working on iOS 10.3.2

Comment: Try to put an alert in it and check in foreground mode.

Comment: see this once for ref https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39382852/didreceiveremotenotification-not-called-ios-10/39383027#39383027

Comment: @mag_zbc assuming you are working on iOS9 to use this method and not on ios10 and UNUserNotificationCenter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which iOS version you are working on ?

> There are different methods for iOS 9 and iOS 10.

**Below are the ones for iOS 10**

```
    //Called when a notification is delivered to a foreground app.
    @available(iOS 10.0, *)
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

    }


    //Called to let your app know which action was selected by the user for a given notification.
    @available(iOS 10.0, *)
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

    }
```

For iOS 9, make sure to register your notification in **didBecomeActive**

```
UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.sound, .alert, .badge], categories: nil))
UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

and in your **didReceiveRemoteNotification**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification data: [AnyHashable : Any]) {

if application.applicationState == .active {
//foreground state
 }

}
```

Best approach would be to put a debugger in **didReceiveRemoteNotification** and check further.

Comment: Make sure to  import UserNotifications

check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/q/38940193/2570153

Comment: Although I'm using Objective-C, not Swift, that is the correct answer. I forgot to implement `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` methods, which are called in foreground instead of `didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` for iOS 10

Comment: @mag_zbc Awesome !